# Dapper changing connection string at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have three identical database servers (DDL wise) that my application connects to.

I want let application users decide which database they want to connect to.

This is a ASP.NET Core 2.1 API project, which implements both service and repository patterns (database queries are called using Dapper, but this can be changed).

I could simply put server name as a parameter in my Domain project, but I don't want this to know anything about database servers we have, neither I want my Repository to know that there could are multiple servers.

So it's just application side that can decide which database server to connect to at run-time.

I was able to find samples and suggestions for EF Core, but not much for anything else, particularly Dapper.

So my question is. How would I let users change database server at run time while keeping domain and repository unaware that multiple servers are there?

Comment: How will the user tell you which database they want to use ? Via incoming API request?

Comment: @cl0ud Correct. Probably as part of request object (maybe as header). We have a finite amount of servers and they change very.very.very rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this case I would suggest having your connection strings either stored in environment variables or appsettings.json files. Lets say the user wants to access "server1" , this would come in from your api and you could then get out the relevant connection string in your repository layer like so

`var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(serverToUse);`

Where `serverToUse` is "server1" passed in from the api. I prefer storing my connection strings in environment variables as its stored directly on the host machine, instead of the application. You could also do this via appsettings

`"Server1" : "Your connection string here"` in your appsettings.json

You could also do this in your service layer and have the service layer pass the connection string to the repository . Pick your flavor. In this case the repositories are not concerned with what connection you are using as long as its present in either environment variable or appsettings.